# Package blocking conda install -- python

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda

Whenever I try to install any package using 'conda install' it gives me the same error message every time.

```
Fetching package metadata ........CondaHTTPError: HTTP Error: Could not find URL: https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm.git@master/linux-64/
```

For some reason the tqdm package is hung up and blocking all my other packages from being installed. I can't figure out how to resolve this. Any suggestions?

Comment: did you try to unistall `tqdm` or ask on `anaconda` web page ?

Comment: When I try to uninstall it it says, ".PackageNotFoundError: Package not found: ' ' no packages found to remove from environment: /home/user/anaconda3" even though it does appear there when I type 'conda list'

Answer (score 0):

This is the result of the tqdm package being set as a channel. This is not a valid channel. This can be resolved by removing "https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm.git@master/linux-64/" from the channels list in the .condarc file.

1. To see the location of the condarc (config) file type 'conda info'
2. To remove the invalid channel open the condarc file with text editor and delete the line pertaining to the channel.